# how get query string with route attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My project is .net core and if I open this URL `domain.com?param1=val1&param2=val2` it hit this action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

in stand of `HomeController ==> Index()` I want if someone requests URL like this `domain.com?param1=val1&param2=val2` hit this controller `RouteController ==> Index()`:

```
public class RouteController : Controller
{
     [Route(@"{*:regex(([^=]+)\=([^&]+))")]
     public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

I think I should use `[Route(@"{*:regex(([^=]+)\=([^&]+))")]` but it doesn't work!

Comment: Are you wanting to change the controller that the root URL of your application points to or are you wanting to redirect to a different endpoint based on query parameters?

Comment: Look at this to set up your routes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @LoLo2207 They probably needs the netcore 3.1 link though - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-up-conventional-route-1

Comment: @ArshamCoder: Be more specific, please. What the required URL structure rules? The query parameters names might be different or only `param1`, `param2`?

Comment: I want if someone writes query string after my main domain the `RouteController/Index` handle the request but by default it hit `HomeController/Index` and I don't want to use redirect method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you wanna achieve the scenario like when user send request with `domain.com`, It will route to `Home/Index` normally, But when user send request with `domain.com?{any query string}`, It will route to `Route/Index`?

I try to custom `IRouteConstraint` and add it will the route templated, Hope it is what you want.

```
public class MyRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Query.Count > 0)
            {
                // Route to Route/Index if query string is present
                return false;
            }

            // Route to Home/Index if no query string is present
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                constraints: new { customConstraint = new MyRouteConstraint() }
                );

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "query",
                 pattern: "{controller=route}/{action=Index}"
            );
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]